# Generating function of a recurrent relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Problem: Find the generating function for the recurrent relation:
$$f_n=2f_{n-1}+\frac 12 f_{n-2},$$
where
$$f_0=f_1=1.$$
My idea was to first find a few of the beginning values and then try to make into some sum of an infinite series, but  I had no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: It will have the form $(a+bx)/(1-2x-x^2/2)$.

Comment: Okay, but how do I find the *a* and *b* then?

Answer (score 2):

> We denote with $F(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty f_n x^n$ a generating function for the recurrence relation
>   \begin{align*}
> f_n&=2f_{n-1}+\frac{1}{2}f_{n-2}\qquad\qquad  n\geq 2\tag{1}\\
> f_0&=1\\
> f_1&=1
> \end{align*}

It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^n]$ to denote  the coefficient of $x^n$ of a series.

> We obtain according to (1) for $n\geq 2$
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^n]F(x)&=2[x^{n-1}]F(x)+\frac{1}{2}[x^{n-2}]F(x)\\
> &=2[x^n]xF(x)+\frac{1}{2}[x^{n}]x^2F(x)\tag{2}\\
> \end{align*}
>
> From which
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^n]F(x)\left(1-2x-\frac{1}{2}x^2\right)&=0\qquad\qquad n\geq 2
> \end{align*}
>   follows.

In (2) we use the rule $[x^{p-q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^qA(x)$.

> We therefore get for $n\geq 0$
>   \begin{align*}
> F(x)\left(1-2x-\frac{1}{2}x^2\right)=a+bx\tag{3}\\
> \end{align*}
>   with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

We can calculate $a$ and $b$ by using $f_0=f_1=1$ and noting that only coefficients of $x^0$ and $x^1$ from the left-hand side of (3) contribute anything to $a+bx$ at the right-hand side of (3).

> We obtain from (3)
>   \begin{align*}
> a&=[x^0]F(x)\left(1-2x-\frac{1}{2}x^2\right)\\
> &=[x^0](1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_nx^n)\left(1-2x-\frac{1}{2}x^2\right)\\
> &=1\\
> b&=[x^1]F(x)\left(1-2x-\frac{1}{2}x^2\right)\\
> &=[x^1](1+x+\sum_{k=2}^\infty f_nx^n)\left(1-2x-\frac{1}{2}x^2\right)\\
> &=[x^1](1+x)(1-2x)\\
> &=-1
> \end{align*}
>
> We conclude
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{F(x)}&\color{blue}{=\frac{1-x}{1-2x-\frac{1}{2}x^2}}\\
> &\color{blue}{=1+x+\frac{5}{2}x^2+\frac{11}{2}x^3+\frac{49}{4}x^4+\cdots}
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

$$g(x)=f_0+f_1x+\sum_{n=2}^\infty f_nx^n
=1+x+2\sum_{n=2}^\infty f_{n-1}x^n+\frac12\sum_{n=2}^\infty f_{n-2}x^n\\
=1+x+2x\sum_{n=2}^\infty f_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\frac{x^2}2\sum_{n=2}^\infty f_{n-2}x^{n-2}\\
=1+x+2x(g(x)-1)+\frac{x^2}2g(x)$$

and you solve this linear equation in $g(x)$.

Comment: It's a good idea, but a few surrounding words of exposition (at your convenience) would be welcome.  E.g. one might surmise the resulting solution $g(x)$ is a rational function of $x$, or something similarly brief.

Comment: I don't see why it would help to know ahead of time that it is a rational function. The real "tricks" are the play with the indexes/exponents and the pulling of the first terms out of the summations. I have added one step.